# Why PHPmyAdmin works on Windows 10 and not Windows 11?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, windows-10, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11 and tried to install XAMPP on this machine. It installed Apache correctly, but when going to mySQL this appears:

[image: mySQL cannot connect]

I tried everything I found online to fix this problem in order to install WordPress locally. Then I "fixed" the problem following this tutorial [Fixing connection to mySQL](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-fix-an-error-of-phpmyadmin-access-denied-in-xamp-mysql/)

After this, at least PHPmyAdmin opened. However, when installing Wordpress, it did not recognise the database (I created the database and made sure the password, the username and the name of the database were correct, together with the privileges).
I spent countless hours trying each and every tutorial I found on the internet to solve this. In the end I resorted to installing XAMPP on a Windows 10 machine. Finally, everything worked out of the box (on Windows 10) without following any tutorials.

Any ideas of why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

The picture says your credentials are incorrect.
Try resetting the password for the MySQL user.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it looks like you didn't provide a proper configuration (last line in your screenshot). You need to have a `config.inc.php` file with appropriate credentials and server details (even in the `localhost` case) in the root of your `phpmyadmin` installation. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install-1 for reference.

Also make sure, that access for the respective user is allowed in the `mySQL` installation (individual database access but also `mySQL` configuration as well, in case of a root access https://linuxconfig.org/mysql-allow-root-remote-access, the latter being discouraged).

After that, of course make sure that your `mySQL` server is actually running and the firewall allows for access on the port (default: 3306) that you set, which should be the default case for connections to the `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I did exactly the same on Windows 10 and it worked. However, on Windows 11 it always gives me error. I will try following the pages you recommended. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I tried this solution and it worked. It still does not answer why I have to do this on Windows 11, while it works out of the box on Windows 10, but in the end, it got solved.

I share this for all of those who are going through the same issue.
In this link, the author recommends changing some parameters in the confg.inc.php file to solve the problem.

[Solution that worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70844365/9780735)

Comment: What a mess, migrated from Stackoverflow and it's a duplicate of this one on stackoverflow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824224/phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-is-not-completely-configured/70844365#70844365

Comment: I don't know why, but after changing the MySQL port to 3307 it stopped working. When I changed again to 3306, it worked again. A note for those who can run into the same issue.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you added a summary of whats in the link.